# VB.NET post data in php

Tags: php, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to access the post data sent from VB.net in PHP. But the POST data seems to be empty. I don't know much about vb.net.

**vb.net code**

```vb
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Net.Security

Public Class frmRegistration

Dim xx As Integer
Dim yy As Integer

Private Sub txtPhoneNo_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtPhoneNo.KeyPress
    Select Case e.KeyChar
        Case "0" To "9"
        Case vbBack
        Case Else
            e.KeyChar = ""
    End Select
End Sub

Private Function UrlSend(ByRef url As String)

    Dim reader As StreamReader
    Dim resUri As String
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    Try

        Dim Res As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse()
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        response = req.GetResponse
        resUri = response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        resUri = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Return resUri
    Catch ex As Exception

        Return ex.Message
    End Try

End Function

'Function Send(ByRef url As String, ByVal key As String) As String
'    Dim TID = key
'    Try
'        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
'        request.Method = "POST"
'        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TID)
'        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
'        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
'        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
'        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
'        dataStream.Close()

'        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
'        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
'        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
'        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
'        reader.Close()
'        dataStream.Close()
'        response.Close()
'        Return responseFromServer

'    Catch ex As Exception
'        If Ping_Internet("www.google.com") = 1 Then
'            MsgBox("Server not responding. Please try later.")
'        End If
'        Me.Close()
'        End
'        Return DBNull.Value.ToString
'    End Try
'End Function

Public Function Ping_Internet(ByVal Activeurl As String) As Integer
    Dim contact As String
    Try
        contact = My.Settings("TollFree").ToString
        Dim strip = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Activeurl).AddressList(0).ToString
        Dim ping As New System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
        If ping.Send(strip).Status = IPStatus.Success Then
            Return 1
        Else
            MsgBox("You are not connected to the Internet. If you are unable to get connected, contact us for help on our toll-free number(" & contact & ") at any time. ")
            End
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("You are not connected to the Internet. If you are unable to get connected, contact us for help on our toll-free number(" & contact & ") at any time. ")
        End
    End Try
    Return 0
End Function

Function Domain_Check(ByVal emailid As String) As Boolean
    If emailid.Contains("@") Then
        Dim Domain As String() = emailid.Split("@")
        Dim br As Boolean
        Try
            Dim ipHost As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Domain(1))
            br = True
            Return br
        Catch se As SocketException
            br = False
            Return br
        End Try
    Else
        Return False
    End If

End Function

Function IsValidEmailFormat(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim a As New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(s)
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try

    If Domain_Check(s) = True Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return True
End Function

Private Sub pnlOk_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles pnlOk.Click
    If txtName.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter Your Name!")
        txtName.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf txtPhoneNo.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter Your Phone Number!")
        txtPhoneNo.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf IsValidEmailFormat(txtEmail.Text.ToString.Trim) = False Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter a Valid Email Id!")
        txtEmail.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf txtKey.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter Product Key Which Was Provided In Your Mail!")
        txtKey.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim url = My.Settings("checkkey").ToString
    Dim key = "rqtoken=" & txtEmail.Text.Trim & "|" & txtKey.Text.Trim
    Dim resp = UrlSend(url & "?" & key).ToString.Trim
    If resp = "OK" Then
        Setregistry()
    Else
        MsgBox(resp)
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Setregistry()
    Try
        If WinVersion() Then
            Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Services")
        End If
        Dim Fullmsg As String = txtName.Text.Trim & "|" & txtPhoneNo.Text.Trim & "|" & txtEmail.Text.Trim & "|" & txtKey.Text.Trim
        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Services", "xxxxxxx", AESEncrypt(Fullmsg), Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
        Application.Restart()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Function AESEncrypt(ByVal PlainText As String) As String
    Dim InitialVector As String = "CanEncryption123"
    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PlainText)) Then
        Return ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim InitialVectorBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector)
    Dim PlainTextBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PlainText)
    Dim KeyBytes As Byte() = {Convert.ToByte(170), Convert.ToByte(89), Convert.ToByte(62), Convert.ToByte(253), Convert.ToByte(87), Convert.ToByte(232), Convert.ToByte(224), Convert.ToByte(53), Convert.ToByte(148), Convert.ToByte(2), Convert.ToByte(68), Convert.ToByte(185), Convert.ToByte(49), Convert.ToByte(60), Convert.ToByte(133), Convert.ToByte(82), Convert.ToByte(136), Convert.ToByte(27), Convert.ToByte(239), Convert.ToByte(160), Convert.ToByte(91), Convert.ToByte(67), Convert.ToByte(207), Convert.ToByte(233)}
    Dim SymmetricKey As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
    SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
    Dim CipherTextBytes As Byte() = Nothing
    Using Encryptor As ICryptoTransform = SymmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes)
        Using MemStream As New MemoryStream()
            Using CryptoStream As New CryptoStream(MemStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                CryptoStream.Write(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length)
                CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
                CipherTextBytes = MemStream.ToArray()
                MemStream.Close()
                CryptoStream.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    SymmetricKey.Clear()
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(CipherTextBytes)
End Function


Private Sub pnlCancel_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles pnlCancel.Click
    txtName.Text = ""
    txtPhoneNo.Text = ""
    txtEmail.Text = ""
    txtKey.Text = ""
    txtName.Focus()
End Sub

Public Function WinVersion() As Boolean
    Dim ver = Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major
    If ver > 5 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Private Sub pnlOk_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles pnlOk.MouseEnter, pnlOk.MouseLeave
    If pnlOk.Tag = 1 Then
        pnlOk.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.ok_bttn_hover
        pnlOk.Tag = 2
    ElseIf pnlOk.Tag = 2 Then
        pnlOk.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.ok_bttn
        pnlOk.Tag = 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub pnlCancel_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles pnlCancel.MouseEnter, pnlCancel.MouseLeave
    If pnlCancel.Tag = 1 Then
        pnlCancel.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.cancel_bttn_hover
        pnlCancel.Tag = 2
    ElseIf pnlCancel.Tag = 2 Then
        pnlCancel.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.cancel_bttn
        pnlCancel.Tag = 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub pcbMin_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles pcbMin.Click
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub

Private Sub pcbCross_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles pcbCross.Click
    End
End Sub

Private Sub pnlPan_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles pnlPan.MouseHover
    xx = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - Me.Left
    yy = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - Me.Top
End Sub

Private Sub pnlPan_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles pnlPan.MouseMove
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Me.Left = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - xx
        Me.Top = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - yy
    Else
        xx = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - Me.Left
        yy = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - Me.Top
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Label3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click

End Sub
End Class




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="Reg_Scan.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
        <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
            <listeners>
                <add name="FileLog"/>
                <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
                <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="FileLog"
             type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
             initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
        <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
        <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
<userSettings>
    <xxx_xxxx.My.MySettings>
        <setting name="TollFree" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="checkkey" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://www.xxxx.com/xxxx.php</value>
        </setting>
    </xxx_xxxx.My.MySettings>
</userSettings>
```

**Php code**

```
<?php

if($_POST)
{

$email = $_POST["emailid"];
$key = $_POST["key"];

try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx_xxx_xx', 'xxxxx',   'xxxxxx');
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email=:email");

$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();

$rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if ($rows > 0) {


if ( $rows->license_key == $key )
{
echo 'OK'

} else {

echo 'Invalid License Key
Please check your license key or Contact Support Admin
xxx@xxx.com';

}
} else {
echo 'Invalid Email ID
Please check your Email ID or Contact Support Admin
xxx@xxx.com';
}

} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
}
?>
```

The php code is working fine as I tested it with an HTML form. Need help in finding why the vb.net form is not sending any post data.

Comment: Install fiddler and check what is being sent/received.

Comment: Are you posting to a different domain? Sometimes the default is to not allow this. It's called CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). More info can be found at http://enable-cors.org/ =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I installed Fiddler and saw that the VB.NET code was generating GET get request as

```
GET/license_register.php?rqtoken=username@mail.com%7Cpassword
```

which has the value as

```
username@mail.com|password
```

modified my php code to read the GET parameters

```
$getstring = $_GET["rqtoken"];
list($email, $key) = explode("|", $getstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your commented out 'Send' method will work better than the method you have in there now.

But you need to change the second line - I don't know if the parameter name "tid" is correct, but you can adjust that.

```
Function Send(ByRef url As String, ByVal key As String) As String
    Dim TID = "tid=" & key;
    Try
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        request.Method = "POST"
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TID)
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()

        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        response.Close()
        Return responseFromServer

    Catch ex As Exception
        If Ping_Internet("www.google.com") = 1 Then
            MsgBox("Server not responding. Please try later.")
        End If
        Me.Close()
        End
        Return DBNull.Value.ToString
    End Try
End Function
```